# Multiply a list by the elements of other list

Tags: python, list

I have this list of list, with a series of values:

```
factors = [1,2,3]
values = [[1,2,3],[3,1,4],[5,5,2]]
```

I want to multiply each list1 in values, but the corresponding element of list1. I am trying with this:

```
factors = [1,2,3]
values = [[1,2,3],[3,1,4],[5,5,2]]
multiply = []
for i in factors:
    multiply = [values[i]*i]
```

But it does not work. The expected value would be:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 2, 8], [15, 15, 6]]
```

Comment: why the `numpy` flag? Do you want the solution to use `numpy`?

Comment: @L.Grozinger I thought it could help. I deleted the `numpy` flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
factors = [1, 2, 3]
values = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

multiply = []
for idx, lst in enumerate(values):
    multiply.append([factors[idx] * x for x in lst])

print(multiply)
```

For a list comprehension version of the above code, see @Hommes answer

Comment: It does give the expected value

Comment: I am sorry. Could you update it to a more general scenario as I edited in the post

Comment: This solution will work for more general scenarios (try plugging in different values)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Given more general setup of the problem I changed the comprehension

Solution with list comprehension:

```py
factors = [1, 2, 3]
values = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 4], [5, 5, 2]]
multiply = [[factors[idx] * elem for elem in lst] for idx, lst in enumerate(values)]
```

```
Out[39]: [[1, 2, 3], [6, 2, 8], [15, 15, 6]]
```

Comment: imagine I have other factors. Can you put it in a more general way? I edited the problem to be more general

Comment: updated it to be able to solve the more general use-case you formulated

Answer (score 1):

There is a few problems with the code as it is:

### Python uses zero-indexing

The first element of a list in Python has the index `0`. In your for loop:

```
for i in factor:
    multiply = [values[i]*i]
```

The last iteration will try to access `values[3]`. But `values` has only 3 elements, so the last element is `values[2]`, *not* `values[3]`.

### Multiplication `*` of a list and an integer doesn't actually multiply

Multiplying a list by an `Int`, say `n` gives you a new list that concatenates the original `n` times. For example:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

The most straightforward way of actually broadcasting the multiplication over the list is to use a 'list comprehension'. For example:

```
>>> [3*x for x in [1,2,3]]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Applying this into your example would look something like:

```
for i in factors:
    multiply = [i*x for x in values[i-1]]
```

### You are only keeping the last calculation in `multiply`

Each go around your `for` loop you assign a new value to `multiply`, overwriting whatever was there previously. If you want to collect all your results, then you should `append` to the `multiply` list.

```
multiply.append([i*x for x in values[i-1]])
```

All together, your example is fixed as:

```
factors = [1,2,3]
values = [[1,2,3],[3,1,4],[5,5,2]]
multiply = []
for i in factors:
    multiply.append([i*x for x in values[i-1]])
```

### Improvements

However, there are still ways to improve the code in terms of concision and readability.

The root of the problem is to multiply a list's elements by a number. `*` can't do it, but you can write your own function which can:

```
def multiply_list(X, n):
    return [n*x for x in X]
```

Then you can use this function, and a list comprehension, to remove the `for` loop:

```
multiply = [multiply_list(x, i) for (x, i) in zip(values, factors)]
```

Or, if you think it is readable, then you can just use the nested list comprehension, which is much more concise:

```
multiply = [[factor * x for x in value] for (value, factor) in zip(values, factors)]
```

Comment: The code does not give the expected result. It results in `multiply = [[3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9]]` and it should be `multiply = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, all the code above works as intended for me. Simply copy pasting the code should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for a one liner. Try this

```
multiply = [[x * y for y in list1] for x in list1]
```